# How can i read this particular json which has a number as a key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, multidimensional-array

Please see json below

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "john",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "amount": "9000",
      "slip": "/image'/loidsds.jpg"
    },
    "method": "pump"
  }
}
```

I am trying to read amount and slip how can i manage to do this is PHP ?

I have tried the following

$object->data->1->amount and $object->data->1->slip

I got some errors please help me find an alternative

Comment: `$object->data->1->amount` and `$object->data->1->slip` maybe? What have you tried? Are you getting any kind of error? Sidenote; maybe `data` should be array, unless you explicitly need `1` as a key?

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested sadly it does not work. Please use an online editor you will observe the response.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `{}` around the `1`. The more important part of my comment was asking you to show what you have already tried; don't ignore that in favour of pointing out an omission. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72004851/edit) and provide more information.

Comment: Yes Tim {} solved my problem thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode as an array by passing a truthy value as the second argument to `json_decode()`:

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
$amount = $json['data'][1]['amount'];
$slip = $json['data'][1]['slip'];
```

Or decode as an object, but then you have to brace the 1 because it's not normally a valid attribute name:

```
$json = json_decode($string);
$amount = $json->data->{1}->amount;
$slip = $json->data->{1}->slip;
```